# craco is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: reactjs, dependencies

I forked and cloned an OpenSource project, and installed all the required dependencies.

There was an error stating that "Craco is not an Internal or External Command", I checked for package.json

```
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

I have been familar with ReactJs for quite some time but this is the first time I'm facing this issue and don't know what to do.